# Задача на циклы и списки Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список:

```
grid=[['.','.','.','.','.','.',],
      ['.','0','0','.','.','.',],
      ['0','0','0','0','.','.',],
      ['0','0','0','0','0','.',],
      ['.','0','0','0','0','0',],
      ['0','0','0','0','0','.',],
      ['0','0','0','0','.','.',],
      ['.','0','0','.','.','.',],
      ['.','.','.','.','.','.',]]
```

Используя вложенные циклы получить вывод в консоль такого вида:

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Добился пока вывода только одной строки следующим кодом:

```
grid=[['.','.','.','.','.','.',],
      ['.','0','0','.','.','.',],
      ['0','0','0','0','.','.',],
      ['0','0','0','0','0','.',],
      ['.','0','0','0','0','0',],
      ['0','0','0','0','0','.',],
      ['0','0','0','0','.','.',],
      ['.','0','0','.','.','.',],
      ['.','.','.','.','.','.',]]
for i in range (len(grid)):
    print(end='')
    for a in range (len(grid[i])):
        s = grid[i][a]
        print(s, end='')
        break
```

Питон только начал изучать

Comment: `print("\n".join("".join(x) for x in zip(*grid)))`

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Поменяй местами циклы - вывод же явно транспонированный.
2. Для вывода перевода строки не надо указывать пустой end. К тому же, логичнее разместить его после вывода строки, а не до.
3. А что в этом коде вообще забыл `break`?